# Relocate texture regions with pixel shader

Tags: shaders, directx, fragment-shader, post-processing

I'm new to DirectX and pixel shader development. I want to know how to relocate region of input image in post processing.

[image: Quadrants of image re-arranged]

What I want to achieve is to divide my image into 4 pieces and then relocate them clockwise or counterclockwise.

Comment: Hello! I rejected your edit on the accepted answer. While it would have made sense in the context of the answer, it is perfectly acceptable to post it an answer of your own. This helps folks realise that it is exactly what you, the author, used for a solution

Comment: @Vaillancourt Thank you for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have an input texture coordinate variable called `uv`, running from (0,0) in the bottom-left to (1,1) in the top right.

If you wrote just

```
return tex2D(InputTexture, uv);
```

...then we'd pass through the source texture to the output texture unchanged. So to get the re-arrangement you want, we'll need to play with the `uv` coordinates a bit.

First, we can do some rounding to establish which quadrant we're in:

```
float2 floored = floor(uv * 2);
float2 quadRelative = uv - (floored * 0.5f);
```

`floored` will take on the values (0,1) (1,1) (0,0) and (1,0) in the input quadrants you labelled 1-4, respectively, and `quadRelative` will give our pixel's texture coordinate offset from the bottom-left of its containing quadrant.

Now we can remap our quadrants as desired. If we want to shuffle counter-clockwise, then we need to sample from the next quadrant clockwise:

```
(0,1)->(1,1)
(1,1)->(1,0)
(1,0)->(0,0)
(0,0)->(0,1)
```

Here's a formula that achieves that:

```
float2 remapped = float2(floored.y, 1 - floored.x);
```

(The formula to rotate in the opposite direction is left as an exercise for the reader )

And finally we can reconstruct our new uv by adding our relative offset to our new quadrant:

```
float2 samplePoint = 0.5f * remapped + quadRelative;
```

You can pass this modified texture coordinate into your sampling function to read from this new quadrant. (I showed the old-style `tex2D()` version above, but this works just as well with other sampling functions)

You'll want to ensure that mipmapping is disabled for your source texture sampler — otherwise the discontinuities in sampling coordinates at the quadrant boundaries will make the GPU think it needs to read from a tiny mip level, resulting in unnecessary blurry pixels. If you can't disable mipmapping, then you can use the gradients from the original `uv` variable with `tex2Dgrad()` or similar.

Comment: Thank you. It worked